# Does the BJP government have any internal connections with big corporations?

Tags: india

Indian farmers have been protesting on the streets for the last few months to urge the government to revoke the three new farming laws which they say will leave them at the mercy of giant corporations. However, the Modi-led BJP government seems to be uncompromising.

I don't understand why the Modi government is so stubborn. Does the BJP government have any internal connections with big corporations such as Reliance, Adani, and Larsen-Toubro?

Comment: Right now I think this is asking for the internal motivations of the BJP. Given that this has already been answered, maybe it would be better to ask a new question about how the BJP has reacted to the protests in public. Surely there will have been some public response where they defend the laws they drafted / passed?

Comment: BJP government?

Comment: @JoeW BJP stands for Bharatiya Janata Party, the current ruling party of India.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thanks, that info would be useful in the question itself to make it more clear what is being asked.

Answer (score -4):

Modi's government is neoliberal and hence corporate friendly. Hence it's policy of disbanding protections of the agricultural sector against corporate capture. That this should have provoked a huge backlash should have forseen, after all, the agricultural sector is the largest employer in India.

His government wants to face down the protests in the same way Thatcher's neoliberal government faced down the miners in the 1980s in Britain. There's nothing stopping them from revoking those laws amd so they should given that India is a democratic polity. The people should be listened to.